# Limit point of set $A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Consider set $$A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ show that 0 is only limit point. Though I prove that but to prove 1 is not a limit point. For this  consider neighborhood  $(1/2,3/2)$ of 1, so if we delete 1 from it we get points like 0.6 , 0.7, 0. 8 but the set $A$ also contains it as it is between 0 to 1. Please let me know where I am incorrect.

Comment: $A$ does not have any point in the open interval $\left(\frac12,\frac32\right)$ apart from $1$ itself. So $1$ is not a limit point.

Comment: $A$ is a subset of $(0,1]$ but it definitely does not contain points like $0.6$.

Comment: But as 0.6, 0.7 0.8 belongs to (1/2,3/2) also 0.6, 0.7 and 0.8 belong to $A$.

Comment: I mean $A$ is between 0 to 1

Comment: Do you agree with $0.6\notin\{\frac1{n}\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$?

Comment: I have understood the problem I was confused with intervals. Thanks all of you